# Não consigo fazer injeção de dependência

Tags: c#, asp.net, injeção-de-dependência

Estou trabalhando com `ASP.NET CORE 2` e é uma aplicação em Camadas.

Este é meu `ConfigureServices` no `Startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<DbContext, ApplicationContext>();
        services.AddTransient<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Erro que aparece ao iniciar a apilicação (Atualizado):

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ddd.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationContext' while attempting to activate 'ddd.Infrastructure.Repositories.UsuarioRepository'.

Segue minha `UsuarioRepository`

```
public class UsuarioRepository : Repository<Usuario>, IUsuarioRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public UsuarioRepository(ApplicationContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool ValidarUsuarioSenha(Usuario usuario)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Segue meu `ApplicationContext`

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private string strConnection
    ="";

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(strConnection);
        }
    }
}
```

*Pergunta Atualizada.

Answer (score 1):

Faltam duas injeções para seu código funcionar corretamente, 1º do Repositório e 2º do seu contexto, seu código deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<DbContext, ApplicationContext>();
    services.AddTransient<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

No seu `UsuarioRepository` e no `Repository` use o `DbContext` invés do `ApplicationContext` pois na injeção de dependência você está "dizendo" quando precisar de um `DbContext` use o `ApplicationContext`

```
public class UsuarioRepository : Repository<Usuario>, IUsuarioRepository
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public UsuarioRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}

//Sua classe deve estar diferente disso, é apenas um exemplo
public class Repository
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public Repository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: não funcionou... esse `DbContext` é do EF core, correto? não funcionou

Comment: Sim, qual mensagem de erro?

Comment: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ddd.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationContext' while attempting to activate 'ddd.Infrastructure.Repositories.UsuarioRepository'.`

Comment: Seria possível adicionar na pergunta seu `contexto` e a classe `UsuarioRepository` e também a `ConfigureServices` atualizada

Comment: Ok Atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo Startup.cs você precisa adicionar também o IUsuarioRepository na injeção de dependencia, seu arquivo ficaria assim:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       services.AddTransient<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
       services.AddTransient<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Comment: Entendi.. agora tá me pedindo outra injeção de dependência... tem que ter todas as DI nesse método?

Comment: Agora tá acontecendo esse erro na camada: `Unable to resolve service for type 'ddd.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationContext' while attempting to activate 'ddd.Infrastructure.Repositories.UsuarioRepository`

Comment: Seu UsuarioRepository deve possuir como argumento seu ApplicationContext, então você precisa registra-lo no seu ServiceCollection sim

Comment: Assim: `services.AddTransient<IUsuarioRepository, ApplicationContext>();` ?? Tá dando erro nessa linha

Comment: Não existe interface para o ApplicationContext?

Comment: Então.. não tem... precisa? Na ApplicationContext é meu Contexto.. tem que ter uma interface?

Comment: SM_S, adicionar a linha services.AddTransient<ApplicationContext, ApplicationContext>(); logo depois de dar o AddTransient no DbContext

Answer (score 0):

Seu usuário service recebe IUsuarioRepository certo, neste caso vc tem que que passar

```
   services.AddTransient<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
   services.AddSingleton<IUsuarioService, UsuarioService>();
```

Ele vai passar o UsuarioRepository para o UsuarioService e UsuarioService para o controller.
Testa ae e me diz se deu certo...